# How does webserver know whom to return form result?

Tags: webserver, http

This is probably a stupid question...

When I submit an online form to a webserver, how does the server know I am the one to return the result to?

I believe it has to do with persistent http connection, but I don't know why I believe it is right.

Thankd

Comment: Many network protocols have both the destination and source addresses in the various headers. When you send an IP packet to another host, the other host knows your IP address. The same holds true for transport protocols like TCP or UDP, which have addresses called ports. TCP segments have both the source and destination TCP addresses.

Comment: Thanks Ron. So other technologies aside, as far as TCP is concerned, it is the same established TCP connection between two IP addresses and their associated ports that ensure correct transfer of data?

Comment: Yes. That is called a connection. In each host, a socket is created, and the socket is a pairing of IP address and TCP port. A TCP connection consists of a pair of sockets (source and destination IP addresses and ports). TCP is a connection-oriented protocol, but UDP is connectionless. HTTP uses TCP for that reason.

Comment: [TFC 793, Transmission Control Protocol](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc793): "_To allow for many processes within a single Host to use TCP
    communication facilities simultaneously, the TCP provides a set of
    addresses or ports within each host.  Concatenated with the network
    and host addresses from the internet communication layer, this forms
    a socket.  A pair of sockets uniquely identifies each connection.
    That is, a socket may be simultaneously used in multiple
    connections._"

Comment: But then under what situations would a socket be simlultaneously used in multiple connections? Isn't a host (not server) port number randomly generated for every process/request?                                                            Edit: if I visit Site A and Site B simultaneously, I would use the same socket in different TCP connections with different servers?

Comment: For example, the same socket would be used by a web server for multiple connections. That would be its IP address and TCP port 80 for HTTP. The remote sockets would distinguish the different connections. Remember, a connection is composed of both the local and remote sockets, so each user browsing the server would be part of a different connection. In real life, one browser will often create multiple connections in order to download different pieces of a web page at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer, it comes from the TCP connection carrying the HTTP data. Modern websites and browsers work together using technologies both above and below HTTP to augment the user experience.

HTTP itself is an application layer protocol, with standard verbs like GET, POST, HEAD, etc. Its important to understand that each of these verbs is "State-less" in that each verb is requested from the server in complete isolation from any other requests. It is also important to understand that each verb implements a request-response pairing, such that a request and its response are intrinsically tied. As such the webserver protocol handlers will always track information about the request so that it can send the response.

A TCP connection presents itself to an application as a pair of IO streams to and from the server. Once a TCP connection is established, applications just read from their input stream and write to their output stream, so there is no (valid) way the app could send the response to anyone else because the output stream is part of your connection. Look into the Berkeley Sockets library if you are interested in examples of how that all comes together.

I hope that helps. The way all this comes together is complicated and takes some time to grok. Just remember, HTTP itself is a remarkably simple protocol which has a very limited set of operations, and while we introduce additional capabilities both below and above HTTP itself, they are not themselves part of HTTP.

Comment: "_A TCP connection presents itself to an application as a pair of IO streams to and from the server._" Actually, TCP knows nothing about clients or servers. TCP is a peer-to-peer protocol. The client/server concept is an application concept.

Comment: I was simplifying in an attempt to be brief. When an pair of applications create a connection between them, both of them have an input and output stream to the other peer. in the case of HTTP, the browser/client initiates a connection to the server, and then writes its requests to its output stream. The Server reads its input stream and gets the request. It then writes a response to its output stream, which the browser can then read off its input stream. I'm trying to explain to the op that Sockets abstracts away the details of the TCP connection as their question is really layer 7.

Comment: Thanks, Frank. That was very informative. Heck, I have never seen the term anti-forgery token.